# Is it a ruby idiom for nil is true?

Tags: ruby

Hi I want to have a condition, which when it is nil, it true, or it call check method and return true/false. For example:

```
(apple.nil? || apple.sweet?) && (pear.nil? || pear.sweet?)
```

It checks if all the fruits are sweet(only apple&pear here). Is there any ruby idiom to simplify this code?

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

> if all the fruits are sweet

```
[apple, pear].compact.all?(&:sweet?)
```

`compact` gets rid of the `nil` elements, then `all?(&:sweet?)` checks if all remaining ones are sweet.

Comment: Even works for the edge case of an empty array: `all?` returns `true` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the solution given by Amadan:

```
fruits.all? { |f| f.nil? || f.sweet? }
```

While the idea of using `compact`, as Amadan correctly suggested, is nice and concise, it will likely create a temporary array of the non-nil elements, while just using `all?` does not need such an array, and iteration stops as soon an element has been encountered  which does not fulfil the condition.

Of course if you only have exactly two fruits in your code, which are mentioned expcitly, I would consider your code better to understand than doing a

```
[apple,pear].all? {...}
```